Widget now showing after .deleteLater on run time
I have an application where I create a QHBoxLayout with some widgets. They are displaying correctly. However, on run time I need to replace some of the widget that that portion is not working. If I clear the whole layout and add new widgets from scratch, it would not show the entire layout edited. If I just replace one widget, it works on the first round but then it only deletes one widget and does not show the new one. I tried .show() and setVisible but that only freezes the application. Any help? It seems like the layout is not updating and showing the modified widgets.
        for n in reversed(range(self.hboxMenu.count())):
            child = self.hboxMenu.itemAt(n)
            oldIcon = child.widget()
            if child.widget() is not None:
                print("widget", oldIcon.name, oldIcon.objectName(), num)
                if oldIcon.objectName() != 100 and oldIcon.objectName() != 200:

                    widgetToRemove = self.hboxMenu.itemAt(n).widget()
                    self.hboxMenu.removeWidget(widgetToRemove)
                    widgetToRemove.setParent(None)
                    if oldIcon.name == oldList[num] and oldIcon.objectName() == str(num + 1):
                    #print("child", oldIcon.name, oldIcon.objectName(), "replace for", newIcon.name, newIcon.objectName())
                    # self.hboxMenu.itemAt(n).widget().deleteLater()


                        # self.hboxMenu.removeWidget(child)
                        # self.hboxMenu.itemAt(n).widget().close()
                        # self.hboxMenu.update()
                        # self.hboxMenu.replaceWidget(self.hboxMenu.itemAt(n).widget(), newIcon)
                        leftIconName = displayMenuIconList[self.viewCount][num]
                        # print("LeftIconName:", leftIconName)
                        img = iconDict[leftIconName]
                        leftButton = PicButton(img, self.iconWidth, self.iconHeight, parent=self.centralwidget)
                        leftButton.name = leftIconName
                        # leftButton.setObjectName(leftIconName)
                        # Add left button to horizontal box group
                        self.hboxMenu.addWidget(leftButton)
                        self.hboxMenu.addWidget(newIcon)

                        # newIcon.clicked.connect(self.openCarSelectionDialog)

                        # self.hboxMenu.insertWidget(num+1, newIcon)
                        # self.hboxMenu.addSpacing(200)
                        self.hboxMenu.update()

                        #newIcon.show()
                        # self.hboxMenu.update()

                        # pass
            elif child.layout() is not None:
                self.clearLayout(child.layout())

I need to replace existing widgets for new ones on run time.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example, possibly complemented with examples of the current vs desired behavior.
